# Filtering spectrum using FIR filters

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

If i have signal values x[T]  and filter coefficients b[i], i can perform filtering using convolution.
[image]

Suppose i have spectrum of x (after FFT) and i need to perform filtering using filters coefficients, how can i perform this? I heard that in frequency domain it will be multiplying, rather than convolution (time domain). But i can't find an equation to use it. I have 614000 values in y = fft(x[T]) vector and 119 filter coefficients (generated using fdatool), i can't multiply them directly ...  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the spectrum of a zero-padded signal values x and the FFT of a zero-padded (to the same length) FIR filter kernel b in order to do fast-convolution by multiplication.  Otherwise, without zero-padding you will end up doing circular convolution instead of linear convolution.

For long data vectors and relatively short FIR filter kernels, and to avoid needing really long FFTs and IFFTs for such, you might want to look into overlap-add or overlap-save fast convolution algorithms.

Comment: i don't really understand what do you mean by "zero padded", if i will multiply x on [b, 0, 0....0] then i will preserve only 119 (length b is 119) low frequencies from spectrum of x.

Comment: question isn't actual anymore

Comment: If b is shorter, the FT of b is effectively longer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your filter to frequency domain as well. Then in frequency domain you can use element-wise multiplication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand how can i handle with different sizes of b and x. In frequency domain b also will have length 119, when x has length 614400, that is the question ...